# Fish Interactive Shell full path

Tags: macos, unix, path, fish

Is there a way in the Fish Interactive shell for the full path to be displayed.  Currently when I navigate to a directory I get the following shell.

```
millermj@Dodore ~/o/workspace
```

but I would rather see

```
millermj@Dodore ~/o-town/workspace
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

With the new fishshell (v2.3) you can do `set -U fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 0`. And it will use the full path. I also use [dartfish](https://github.com/amir20/dartfish) for my theme. See example below:

[image]

Comment: I should have added that I use dartfish theme. Maybe it's part of the theme?

Comment: Not part of the theme. This works for me on fish `2.3.1`.

Comment: The command mentioned above (set -U fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 0) can be configured in config.fish .  In case someone here needs more information.

Comment: Can confirm that this works as of fish 3.1.0 as well.

Answer (score 17):

Here's my version of `prompt_pwd` that should display what you're looking for:

```
function prompt_pwd --description 'Print the current working directory, NOT shortened to fit the prompt'
    if test "$PWD" != "$HOME"
        printf "%s" (echo $PWD|sed -e 's|/private||' -e "s|^$HOME|~|")
    else
        echo '~'
    end

end
```

This will display the tilde for the home directory, as usual, but removes the `sed` command that only pulls the first letter from each directory when you're a few directories deep.

To edit `prompt_pwd` use `funced`. It will allow you to interactively alter the function. From the command line type `funced prompt_pwd`. Once the prompt is displaying to your liking, use `funcsave prompt_pwd` to make the behavior persist in future sessions.

Comment: You don't actually need the `if`, in the home dir, the `sed` will still produce `~`

Comment: Your version shows up on my machine as `/V/Y/U/s/D/p001` instead of `Volumes/Yosemite I am/Users/slippyd/Desktop/p001` (the result of `echo $PWD)`.

Comment: Type `fish_config` in the fish shell, it'll open up a fish-config web interface in your browser. Now you can select from a long list of options for your prompt..

Answer (score 6):

I personally don't like touching the shared/defaults. Fish has a great functions design, so leverage that.

Create `~/.config/fish/functions/prompt_long_pwd.fish` with the contents:

```
function prompt_long_pwd --description 'Print the current working directory'
        echo $PWD | sed -e "s|^$HOME|~|" -e 's|^/private||'
end
```

Then simply edit your `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish` to use `prompt_long_pwd`.  Here is the custom prompt that I use:

**~/.config/fish/config.fish**:

```
set -g __fish_git_prompt_show_informative_status 1
set -g __fish_git_prompt_hide_untrackedfiles 1

set -g __fish_git_prompt_color_branch magenta bold
set -g __fish_git_prompt_showupstream "informative"
set -g __fish_git_prompt_char_upstream_ahead "↑"
set -g __fish_git_prompt_char_upstream_behind "↓"
set -g __fish_git_prompt_char_upstream_prefix ""

set -g __fish_git_prompt_char_stagedstate "●"
set -g __fish_git_prompt_char_dirtystate "✚"
set -g __fish_git_prompt_char_untrackedfiles "…"
set -g __fish_git_prompt_char_conflictedstate "✖"
set -g __fish_git_prompt_char_cleanstate "✔"

set -g __fish_git_prompt_color_dirtystate blue
set -g __fish_git_prompt_color_stagedstate yellow
set -g __fish_git_prompt_color_invalidstate red
set -g __fish_git_prompt_color_untrackedfiles $fish_color_normal
set -g __fish_git_prompt_color_cleanstate green bold
```

**~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish**

```
function fish_prompt --description 'Write out the prompt'

    set -l last_status $status

    if not set -q __fish_prompt_normal
        set -g __fish_prompt_normal (set_color normal)
    end

    # PWD
    set_color $fish_color_cwd
    echo -n (prompt_long_pwd)
    set_color normal

    printf '%s ' (__fish_git_prompt)

    if not test $last_status -eq 0
    set_color $fish_color_error
    end

    echo -n '$ '

end
```

Comment: Most of your answer is unrelated to answering the question.  People want you to delete the unrelated parts.

Answer (score 0):

Create `~/.config/fish/functions/prompt_long_pwd.fish` with:

```
function prompt_long_pwd --description 'Print the full working directory'
        echo $PWD
end
```

In `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish` change `(prompt_pwd) (set_color normal)` to `(prompt_long_pwd) (set_color normal)`.

`(prompt_pwd)` replaces the directory name with the first letter of the directory, which I too sometimes find annoying. You can also probably modify the original command `prompt_pwd`, I have not tried it.

This answer is modified from the earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26682711/14142051) and shows the full directory while keeping the other parts of the default prompt. The key change is in the expression in `~/.config/fish/functions/prompt_long_pwd.fish`.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd give everyone a heads up if you stumbled on this and your fish is not responding to the `fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length` variable try upgrading omf, and then update your omf themes that you're using. Then do some combination of selecting a different theme, reopening the shell, and selecting a different theme again. This is what worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score -4):

The `prompt_pwd` function determines the function to be displayed.  You should be able to write your own version to get what you want.